# How do I read and write large buffers to a process stdin/stdout/stderr in Perl?

Tags: perl, ipc

I want to start a program, send some data to its stdin, read its stdout/stderr and return everything. And if it runs for too long I want to kill it.

I use the low-level unbuffered io function, do everything in chunks, check before writing/reading using select but it **still** fails....

With the following script, `cat` timeouts on the bash man page (300KB) after writing back 5000 bytes. *Why*?

```
$ perl bar.pl
timeout :( at bar.pl line 119.
RES = 9
ERR = <>
IN  = <BASH(1)                       ...> (294439 chars)
OUT = <BASH(1)                       ...> (5000 chars)
```

**UPDATE**: When I use a single IO::Select object and stop capturing stderr, it get almost everything back without a timeout.

Diff:

```
--- old.pl  2013-11-20 17:08:19.000000000 +0100
+++ new.pl  2013-11-20 17:07:58.000000000 +0100
@@ -26,10 +26,6 @@

     my $bufsize = 100;

-    my $insel = IO::Select->new();
-    my $outsel = IO::Select->new();
-    my $errsel = IO::Select->new();
-
     $fderr = gensym;
     my $pid = open3($fdin, $fdout, $fderr, $cmd, @args) or die "open3 $!";

@@ -39,9 +35,9 @@
     my $len = length($progin);
     my $off = 0;

-    $insel->add($fdin);
-    $outsel->add($fdout);
-    $errsel->add($fderr);
+    my $sel = IO::Select->new();
+    $sel->add($fdin);
+    $sel->add($fdout);

     if ($len <= 0) {
         close $fdin;
@@ -59,7 +55,7 @@
             last;
         }

-        if ($len > 0 && $insel->can_write($select_timeout)) {
+        if ($len > 0 && $sel->can_write($select_timeout)) {
             $ret = syswrite $fdin, $progin, $bufsize, $off;
             if (!defined $ret) {
                 warn "in ndef";
@@ -74,7 +70,7 @@
             }
         }

-        if ($outsel->can_read($select_timeout)) {
+        if ($sel->can_read($select_timeout)) {
             my $buf;
             $ret = sysread($fdout, $buf, $bufsize);
             if(!defined $ret) {
@@ -84,16 +80,6 @@
             $progout .= $buf;
         }

-        if ($errsel->can_read($select_timeout)) {
-            my $buf;
-            $ret = sysread($fderr, $buf, $bufsize);
-            if(!defined $ret) {
-                warn "err ndef";
-                last;
-            }
-            $progerr .= $buf;
-        }
-
         $ret = waitpid($pid, WNOHANG);
         # still exists, continue
         if ($ret == 0) {
```

The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Open3;
use Symbol 'gensym';
use Time::HiRes 'time';
use POSIX ':sys_wait_h';
use IO::Select;
use Getopt::Std;
use File::Temp;


my $in = `man -P cat bash`;
my ($res, $out, $err) = run_prog($in, 5, 'cat');

print "RES = $res\n";
print "ERR = <$err>\n";
printf "IN  = <%s...> (%d chars)\n", substr($in, 0, 30), length($in);
printf "OUT = <%s...> (%d chars)\n", substr($out, 0, 30), length($out);

sub run_prog {
    my ($progin, $timeout, $cmd, @args) = @_;
    my ($progres, $progout, $progerr);
    my ($fdin, $fdout, $fderr);

    my $bufsize = 100;

    my $insel = IO::Select->new();
    my $outsel = IO::Select->new();
    my $errsel = IO::Select->new();

    $fderr = gensym;
    my $pid = open3($fdin, $fdout, $fderr, $cmd, @args) or die "open3 $!";


    my $start = time;
    my $ret;
    my $len = length($progin);
    my $off = 0;

    $insel->add($fdin);
    $outsel->add($fdout);
    $errsel->add($fderr);

    if ($len <= 0) {
        close $fdin;
    }

    $progout = '';
    $progerr = '';

    my $select_timeout = 0.1;

    my $toolong = 0;
    while (1) {
        if (time - $start > $timeout) {
            $toolong = 1;
            last;
        }

        if ($len > 0 && $insel->can_write($select_timeout)) {
            $ret = syswrite $fdin, $progin, $bufsize, $off;
            if (!defined $ret) {
                warn "in ndef";
                last;
            }

            $off += $ret;
            $len -= $ret;

            if ($len <= 0) {
                close $fdin;
            }
        }

        if ($outsel->can_read($select_timeout)) {
            my $buf;
            $ret = sysread($fdout, $buf, $bufsize);
            if(!defined $ret) {
                warn "out ndef";
                last;
            }
            $progout .= $buf;
        }

        if ($errsel->can_read($select_timeout)) {
            my $buf;
            $ret = sysread($fderr, $buf, $bufsize);
            if(!defined $ret) {
                warn "err ndef";
                last;
            }
            $progerr .= $buf;
        }

        $ret = waitpid($pid, WNOHANG);
        # still exists, continue
        if ($ret == 0) {
            next;
        }
        # process exited/signaled
        # make a last read
        elsif ($ret > 0) {
            $progres = $?;
            next;
        }
        # process doesn't exists anymore
        else {
            last;
        }
    }

    close $fdout;
    close $fderr;

    # timeout
    if ($toolong) {
        warn "timeout :(";
        kill 9, $pid;
        waitpid($pid, 0);
        $progres = $?;
    }

    return ($progres, $progout, $progerr);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one managed to make this work I've looked harder in CPAN and found the `IPC::Run` module.

```
use IPC::Run;
sub run_prog {
    my ($in, $t, $cmd, @args) = @_;
    my ($out, $err);
    IPC::Run::run([$cmd, @args], \$in, \$out, \$err, IPC::Run::timeout($t));
    return ($?, $out, $err);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have dinked around with this for ages, and can get it to work by replacing the 3 variables that you use for the select() call, with a single variable to which you add all 3 file descriptors. So the code looks like this:

```
my $sel = IO::Select->new();
$sel->add($fdin);
$sel->add($fdout);
$sel->add($fderr);
```

and later on:

```
$sel->can_write($select_timeout);
```

and

```
$sel->can_read($select_timeout)
```

Comment: Still doesn't work (write 5000 bytes and timesout). When I remove `$fderr` from `$sel` and the `if ($sel->can_read(...)` on `$fderr` (ie. when I only capture stdout) it writes 321000 bytes (**almost** good, not 321071) without a timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I looked at it some more and this works every time and doesn't miss any bytes. I'll leave you to add back in the error handling stuff.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Open3;
use Symbol 'gensym';
use Time::HiRes 'time';
use POSIX ':sys_wait_h';
use IO::Select;
use Getopt::Std;
use File::Temp;


my $in = 'a' x 300000;  # Just get 300000 bytes without messing around
my ($res, $out, $err) = run_prog($in, 5, 'cat');

print "RES = $res\n";
print "ERR = <$err>\n";
printf "IN  = <%s...> (%d chars)\n", substr($in, 0, 30), length($in);
printf "OUT = <%s...> (%d chars)\n", substr($out, 0, 30), length($out);

sub run_prog {
    my ($progin, $timeout, $cmd, @args) = @_;
    my ($progres, $progout, $progerr);
    my ($fdin, $fdout, $fderr);

    my $bufsize = 100;    # Or use 4, or 800,000 - they all work now!

    $fderr = gensym;
    my $pid = open3($fdin, $fdout, $fderr, $cmd, @args) or die "open3 $!";

    my $write_set = IO::Select->new($fdin);
    my $read_set  = IO::Select->new($fdout);

    my $start = time;
    my $ret;
    my $len = length($progin);
    my $off = 0;

    if ($len <= 0) {
        close $fdin;
    }

    $progout = '';
    $progerr = '';

    my $select_timeout = 0.1;

    my $toolong = 0;
    while (1) {
        if (time - $start > $timeout) {
            $toolong = 1;
            last;
        }

        if ($len > 0 && IO::Select->select(undef,$write_set,undef,$select_timeout)) {
            $ret = syswrite $fdin, $progin, $bufsize, $off;
            if (!defined $ret) {
                warn "in ndef";
                last;
            }

            $off += $ret;
            $len -= $ret;

            if ($len <= 0) {
                close $fdin;
            }
        }

        if (IO::Select->select($read_set,undef,undef,$select_timeout)) {
            my $buf;
            $ret = sysread($fdout, $buf, $bufsize);
            if(!defined $ret) {
                warn "out ndef";
                last;
            }
            $progout .= $buf;
        }

        $ret = waitpid($pid, WNOHANG);
        # still exists, continue
        if ($ret == 0) {
            next;
        }
        # process exited/signaled
        # make a last read
        elsif ($ret > 0) {
            $progres = $?;
            next;
        }
        # process doesn't exists anymore
        else {
            last;
        }
    }

    close $fdout;
    close $fderr;

    # timeout
    if ($toolong) {
        warn "timeout :(";
        kill 9, $pid;
        waitpid($pid, 0);
        $progres = $?;
    }

    return ($progres, $progout, $progerr);
}
```

Comment: IT WORKS! Well done! I still don't understand what was the reason but thank you!

Comment: AUGH! Actually it still doesn't work! If the program doesn't consume the data fast enough it will block and timeout again... Try `perl -e '$b=0; while(read(STDIN, $b, 1)){print $b;}'` instead of `cat`.

Answer (score -1):

Line:

```
  if ($len > 0 && $insel->can_write($select_timeout)) {
```

shouldn't that be

```
...outsel->can_write...
```

Comment: No. It's the stdin of the child process. You're supposed to write in it.

Comment: I notice that if I increase the buffersize by a factor of 10, it reads 10 times as much data. In fact, it seems to do 50 reads whatever I do - maybe that will help someone (smarter than me!) diagnose the problem. I also note that if you increase the select_timeout to 1 second, it hangs altogether.

Comment: I also changed the `man -P cat bash` stuff into something that is easier to understand and gives a known volume (1 meg) of data, like this `dd if=/dev/zero bs=1m count=1`.